# In Dr. Strangelove, what is the device Soviet Ambassador Sadesky uses near the end of the film?

Tags: stanley-kubrick, dr.-strangelove

As shown here. (O.O2)

Does that device (which looks like a simple pocket watch) play any part of the "Doomsday device"? I've wondered about that for years.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like it's supposed to be a spy camera.  It was a common trope in the 60s that a camera could be hidden in a watch or similar small object.  Note the shutter click noise when he pushes the lever, and then turns the knob to advance the film.

I found some discussion on [The Straight Dope Message Board](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=684657) as to why he would do that.  A common opinion is that he's such a committed Cold Warrior that he wants to spy on the American War Room even when it's absurd because everybody is about to die.